# Check the content of *args in a Class __init__

Tags: python, args

I want to test if in the *args parameter is a string `ti`. If so I want to print `"ti"`. If it is a list where the first element has a length of 1 I want to print "it is a list with len 1 values". If both does not apply, I want to print `"full list"`

Here is my code it does not print anything and I do not know why. Can anyone help me here?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def test_meth(self):

        if self.args == 'ti':
            print('ti')
        elif type(self.args) == list:
            if len(self.args[0]) == 1:
                print('it is a list with len 1 values')
            else:
                print('full list')

my_class = MyClass('ti')
my_class.test_meth()
```

Comment: Perhaps use: `if 'ti' in self.args:`. btw `self.args` will always be a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*args` in `def __init__(self, *args):` will lead `self.args` to store a tuple so the first if-statement will always be `False`. If you want your code to work, you should rewrite it as:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def test_meth(self):
        if self.args == ('ti',):
            print('ti')
        elif len(self.args) == 1 and len(self.args[0]) == 1:
            print('it is a list with len 1 values')
        else:
            print('full list')

my_class = MyClass('ti')
my_class.test_meth()
```

or with more generic (works with any iterable `args`):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    def test_meth(self):
        if len(self.args) == 1 and self.args[0] == 'ti':
            print('ti')
        elif len(self.args) == 1 and len(self.args[0]) == 1:
            print('it is a list with len 1 values')
        else:
            print('full list')

my_class = MyClass('ti')
my_class.test_meth()
```

Comment: I think the OP want to know if `first element has a length of 1`, not that the first element *is* `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The `args` with always be a tuple, not a list, even if there’s only 1 element:

You don’t need to check whether the `self.args` is a tuple/list:

```
def test_meth(self):
    if len(self.args) == 1 and 'ti' in self.args:
        print('ti')
    if self.args and len(self.args[0]) == 1:
        print('list with length 1 len values')
    else:
        print('full list')
```

Comment: I think the OP want to know if `first element has a length of 1`, not that the first element *is* `1`.

Comment: The way I read the question, "full list" should be printed even is `args` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`type(my_class.args)` is `tuple` so you can not compare it to a single value, i.e.

```py
if self.args == 'ti':
```

However, you can do

```py
if "ti" in self.args and len(self.args) == 1:
```

to check that "ti" is the only input.

Comment: Or just `if self.args == ('ti',)`

Answer (score 0):

`self.args` is, like @quamrana mentions, always of type `tuple`, and therefore never equal to `'ti'` or of type `list`. That is why your current code doesn't print anything.

I believe the following does what you describe:

```
class MyClass:                                                              
    def __init__(self, *args):                                              
        self.firstarg = args[0]                                             

    def test_meth(self):                                                    
        if self.firstarg == 'ti':                                           
            print('ti')                                                     
        elif type(self.firstarg) == list:                                   
            if len(self.firstarg) == 1:                                     
                print('it is a list with 1 value')                          
            else:                                                           
                print('full list')                                          

my_object = MyClass('ti')                                                   
my_object.test_meth()                                                       
my_object = MyClass(['ti'])                                                 
my_object.test_meth()                                                       
my_object = MyClass(['ti', 'ti'])                                           
my_object.test_meth()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if no arguments are passed into `MyClass()`? An IndexError may occur.

Comment: that's true, I'll let the caller `except` it in this case :-)